# Outlook 2010 Error "This task could not be updated at this time." Item still processes properly

Tags: 2010, infopath, outlook, approval-process

I have an approval workflow, which sends and email to the person it is assigned to.

The user opens the email through Outlook 2010 and processes their task (approve, reject or reassign task).

After completing their task Outlook return an error message

> This task could not be updated at this time."

However the item does complete its process on the server side.

[image]

Users do have the proper permission to access the task and this issue happens from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue and as per Microsoft

To resolve this, install the 'Form Template Installer Tool' component under 'Microsoft Office InfoPath' using the Office installer for full functionality.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970199)

Comment: I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 and there is no option for "Form Template Installer Tool". Is there another way of installing the tool? Would this need to be installed on the client side or the server side?

Answer (score 0):

If the answer about using the `InfoPath Form Tool` didn't work to fix the issue, it could be (I am guessing your workflow is on a list or a library) lying with specific permission settings?

You might want to look for a `Task List` under `All Site Content` that is specific for the workflow. You need to modify the task lists inherent security settings, as it inherits from the Site, not the list, or library you created it on.

When you create a workflow, it will make a workflow task list for you.  Your workflow task list can be found under "All site content" on the page your list or library is located on.